# Pycharm showing venv and base in the terminal

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

I am curious about my terminal inside the Pycharm after I have established the virtual environment. The screenshot is as follow. Is that normal to have (venv) and (base) in the front? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjZx.png)

Comment: Screenshot missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is `(venv)` comes from PyCharm auto-activating the virtual environment you have configured as a project interpreter and `(base)` is likely `conda` base environment activated in `~/.bashrc` (or similar place). I guess in the terminal outside of PyCharm you only have `(base)`.

## Details

Let me explain what is happening in more detail (Ubuntu and Bash as an example)

1. You've installed e.g. Miniconda on your machine
2. Conda installer patched `~/.bashrc`, e.g. `cat ~/.bashrc`

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/parallels/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/parallels/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/parallels/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/parallels/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

3. Now each time you run a terminal (either a PyChrarm-built-in one or a system one) you will get `(conda)` as Bash sources `~/.bashrc` to start a new shell session
4. With conda activated in the terminal you can run e.g. `conda` command as it was added to the `PATH` environment variable

```
$ which conda
/home/parallels/miniconda3/bin/conda
```

5. `python` command in the terminal will invoke Python from Miniconda as again the `PATH` environment variable was patched

```
$ which python
/home/parallels/miniconda3/bin/python
```

5. Now let's open some project in PyCharm with a virtual environment set as a project interpreter
6. And open a built-in PyCharm terminal
7. Bash source `~/.bashrc`, activates conda and you get `(conda)`
8. PyCharm sources `activate` script of the virtual environment and you get `(venv) (conda)`
9. As the venv was activated last it overwrote conda activation in some places, e.g.

```
$ which python
/home/parallels/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python
```

The question is - should you care?

Probably not, apart from visual clutter, it doesn't affect you much. There are some environment variables left after conda activation which were not overridden by the venv activation but they are unlikely to affect you.

You can remove conda activation logic from `~/.bashrc` if `(base)` bothers you too much. You can always activate it back manually. I believe it only make sense to leave the activation logic in place if you work with conda a lot in the terminal and want to save time re-activating it manually.

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. I think your guess is correct. SO in this case will the (base) environment affect what I am going to do in the (venv) ones?

Comment: I don't think so. Check `which python` and `which pip` to make sure the expected `python` and `pip` executables are gonna be used.

Comment: Does that mean I have virtual environment and conda base environment both exist in the project? How should I stress this issue in this case? Maybe try conda deactivate? Thank you so much!

Comment: Both activated in the terminal to be precise. The project doesn't know about conda. It should not affect you much but you can remove conda activation logic from `~/.bashrc` if you want to remove the pesky `(base)`. I've added more details to the answer to explain what is happening. Hope it helps.